# Deploying a simple VB app with a web help file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, deployment

I'm writing a simple program in VB using VS Community 2017 and want to deploy it to an executable which I can distribute on as CD (or via email).

It's got a .chm help file and I can't work out how to make it work. There are two completely separate questions:

1) How do I call the help file from the F1 key or a menu item? The Help.ShowHelp .NET method allows me to do this, but needs a file name. When the app is copied to the user's system it won't be in the same folder as on my system. So how can the program find the file?

2) How do I get VS to include the .chm file with the program package? Adding it to the project doesn't work.

Comment: If it's two questions then you should post two separate questions.

Comment: 1. `Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "MyFile.chm")` will give you the full path to a file in the same folder as the current EXE.

Comment: 2. Add the file, select Properties, set the `Build Action` to `Content` and `Copy to output directory` to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`.  If that doesn't include it automatically when you publish, you can include it manually from the `Publish` page of the project properties.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great help. I debated whether to ask two questions, but they're related in that the answer to the first may depend on the answer to the second (yes, I probably should have put them in the other order).